# Randomly replacing keywords in a string

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to replace a word in a string with a random number (1 - 10). I've tried a couple methods listed below:

```
sentence = 'replace every every with random number'
s = sentence.replace('every', str(random.randint(1, 11)))
print(s)
```

This works fine, but the problem here is that the number is the same for each word. It will return:

```
'replace 4 4 with random number'
```

or:

```
'replace 7 7 with random number'
```

I've also tried creating a list (1 - 10) of numbers, then using random.choice() in the replace function.

```
sentence = 'replace every every with random number'
lst = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']
s = sentence.replace('every', random.choice(lst))
print(s)
```

But I run into the same problem, where each word is replaced with the same number. Is there any work-around to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace()` replaces every instance of the substring. However there is a parameter you could use: `count` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

```
sentence = 'replace every every with random number'
word_to_replace = 'every'
while word_to_replace in sentence:
    # replace only the first found instance
    sentence = sentence.replace('every', str(random.randint(1, 11)), 1)
print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a third parameter as mentioned defines the maximum number of occurances that you want to replace.

Hence:

```
sentence = 'replace every every with random number'
s = sentence.replace('every', str(random.randint(1, 11)), 1)
print(s)
```

Returns:

```
replace 3 every with random number
```